# Error con libreria Spring en Eclipse: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Tags: spring, eclipse, librería

Hola estoy aprendiendo Spring (concretamente el uso de annotations), he hecho un pequeñísimo programa en eclipse siguiendo instrucciones de un curso online. Debería dar una salida por consola de un simple texto.
Al ejecutar el programa me lanza el siguiente error, creo que relacionado con las librerías de spring:

**Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users....\eclipse\java-2021-03\workspaceEE\Aprendiendo_JavaAnnotations\libs\spring-context-indexer-5.3.8-sources.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.springframework.context.index.processor.CandidateComponentsIndexer not in module**

Estoy usando version 15 de Java, cargué la librería de Spring y la referencié a través de Java Build Path.

He probado a añadir la libreria de Spring tanto en Modulepath como en ClassPath, el error que muestro aquí es cuando está en Modulepath, ya que en ClassPath sale otro error distinto y más verboso.
También he probado a quitar el module-info siguiendo algún consejo pero no hay cambios, finalmente lo he dejado en otro paquete.

EDIT: He usado archivo java para la configuracion prescindiendo del XML inicial. Y parece que tampoco está el problema en el XML, pues el error persiste.

¿Alguna idea de como desbloquear?

[image: árbol proyecto java]

Comment: ¿Qué curso es? Parece un poco anticuado, si estás usando ficheros XML para la configuración

Comment: Es de "Pildoras Informáticas" (Curso Spring). Juan, el profe, ya indica que actualmente no se hace así, pero empieza usando XML, luego annotations,... lo hace para explicar que es lo que hay detrás, lo cual no me parece mal, y aunque sea una forma antigua debería funcionar, y me interesa conocer como resolver este error, por seguir el avance del curso y por conocer más de la herramienta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Que onda, tenia el mismo problema por que sigo el mismo curso, debes colocar todas las librerias en el ClassPath y removerlas del ModulePath, apply and close, run y deberia funcionar o al menos en mi caso asi fue, espero te sirva.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Rodrigo Leyva, aunque ya había intentado moverlo al Classpath, me daba otra serie de errores. Finalmente decidí usar Spring Tool Suite, que en definitiva sigue siendo Eclipse, y me va genial. Estoy siguiendo otros cursos interesantes. Compartimos lo que necesites. Gracias